# ImageMagick, Convert command degrades image actual Quality

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, image-processing, imagemagick, minimagick

I have been trying to convert `JPG` image which is in `CMYK` format to `sRGB`format with `imagemagick` library in Ruby on Rails.

But unfortunately, observed that quality of the image degraded after convertion of image by following command:

```
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
  convert << attachment.tempfile.path
  convert.merge! ["-colorspace", "srgb"]
  convert << attachment.tempfile.path
end
```

Is there anything missing here? and looking forward to avoid the deviation.

Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: Maybe show us the before and after images...

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "degraded". I am going to assume that you know that CMYK color gamut is smaller than the sRGB color gamut. While this should work appropriately since the CMYK gamut is contained within the sRGB gamut most converters simply do their best to determine the appropriate color and many fall well short of this. Many conversion from CMYK to sRGB will even place colors outside the CMYK gamut all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the ImageMagick -profile option for better conversion:

```
convert image.jpg -profile sRGB.icc rgb_image.jpg
```

You can look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#color_profile) for more details on ImageMagick.